# Showing KeyError 0 When Using Eclat Algorithm through Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, data-mining

I am reading a dataframe, df_uci. Following are list of columns I have.

name of Column,Total 4085 Cols and First Col is Transaction_ID

[image: 1].

When I am applying the ECLAT algorithm:

```
from pyECLAT import ECLAT
# create an instance of eclat
my_eclat = ECLAT(data=df_uci)
```

It is showing error KeyError 0:. What are possible cause and solution of this error.

1. I already verified that there is not a null or missing values in col or header.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same issue. You just have to rename your columns in your DataFrame to a sequence of numbers. 
In the documentation the top row of the example are the column names, which should reflect what is inside your DataFrame.

```
# From the ECLAT documentation
>>> Example of data format
         0           1           2            3
0        milk        beer        bread        butter
1        coffe       bread       butter       NaN
2        coffe       bread       butter       NaN
```

So instead of having "Transaction_ID", "bomboxipodclassic", "1hanger"... Rename the columns to 0, 1, 2 ... You can achieve it with this:

```
dataFrame = pd.DataFrame(your_data)
attrCount = len(dataFrame.count())
i = 0
for col in dataFrame.columns[:attrCount].tolist():
    dataFrame.rename(columns={col : i}, inplace=True)
    i += 1

eclat_instance = ECLAT(dataFrame, verbose=True)
```